# Use Azure dashboard time grain in pinned workbook query parts

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-monitor

I have created a shared workbook for monitoring several metrics/charts for my team. Parts of the workbook are pinned to dashboard. Workbook has a time range parameter so that pinned parts can use time range configured on dashboard. This allows team members to change dashboard time range to quickly update all charts.
Dashboard also allows to configure time granularity and we need to override automatic time granularity. For example, use 15 minute time granularity even for 3 day time range. I could not find a way to use this granularity parameter from dashboard in workbook parts. Has anyone been able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, workbooks doesn't currently know about any overridden time *granularity* of the dashboard.

Workbooks parts can use the dashboard's time range, which it sounds like you've already done, and if you use syntax like `{timerange:grain}` in your query you'll get an automatic grain based on that time range from the dashboard's time range.

But neither query or metrics steps in workbooks know how to reference the dashboard's overridden granularity or if the dashboard settings specify UTC vs local time.

i've added `9819260: Workbooks: support customized dashboard time granularity` to our backlog, but can't make any promises on when it might be scheduled or implemented

Comment: Does `{timerange:grain}` works for the summarize Operator? I can't make it working. `| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, {TimeRange:grain})` returns the error `Query could not be parsed at '{'`

Comment: are you doing this *in workbooks*?  do you have the right parameter name?  the fact that you got to an error referencing a `{` from the query service implies one of those is not the case, because workbooks would have replaced the parameter.

Comment: I'm not working with workbooks ...

Comment: without using workbooks, this answer won't apply to you